# Directed graph formed by the union of two partial order sets has a kernel?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A kernel of a directed graph $G$ is an independent set $S\subseteq V(G)$ such that for any $v\in V(G)\setminus S$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $sv\in E(G)$.

Let $G$ be the directed graph induced by two partial order sets $P$ and $Q$ on $V(G)$, which means if $u>v$ in $P$ or $Q$, then $uv\in E(G)$.

A claim states that such $G$ has a kernel. I am wondering how to prove it?

I want to take the set $S$ of maximal elements in $P$, which is independent in $P$ and dominates other vertices. But it may be not independent in $Q$. How can we fix it?

Comment: This is wrong as stated. The graph induced by the usual order on $\mathbb Z$ doesn't have a kernel. (Independent sets have at most one element, and you can't reach all elements from any one element.) Perhaps you forgot to add a premise that $G$ is finite?

Comment: Yes, we only consider the finite case.

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly. It should be self-contained without relying on the comments.

Comment: It is a custom to consider only the finite case in graph theory if there is no specification, like the custom to denote $(u,v)$ by $uv$.

Comment: This can be proved by combining the above the construction and induction on $|V(G)|$.

Comment: If you’ve solved the problem, you can [answer your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) so others can profit from the result.